# config server and config client in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, client

Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-05-15T10:29:29.732+05:30  INFO 14600 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused: no further information. Will be trying the next url if available
2023-05-15T10:29:29.732+05:30  WARN 14600 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused: no further information

when i try to connect config server with config client im getting error please assist.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for this error is that the Config Server is not running or is not accessible on specified port. So check if the Config Server is up and running on the specified URL (http://localhost:8888/microservice-config/) or (http://localhost:8888). You can test this by opening the URL in a web browser.

If you see the config content in browser, then verify that the Config Client has the correct URL of the Config Server configured in its configuration file. You can check the bootstrap.yml or application.yml file in the Config Client project to ensure that the URL is correct.
In final step check config server project dependencies and configs.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration) is a good reference